# TinyMC text area isn't encodes correctly to the MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, tinymce-plugins

While saving data to MongoDB, the characters that generated from a text area isn't generates correctly within the database, the output is just none (''), I've tried to change the input's unicode but nothing appeared to work. I will appreciate your help to let me know what I did wrong - and of course I will learn from it ;)

**My whole JS' code**

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express()
var http = require('http').Server(app)
var io = require('socket.io')(http)
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

app.use(express.static(__dirname))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

mongoose.Promise = Promise

var dbUrl = 'mongodb+srv://username:1234@cluster0.iwdr9.mongodb.net/database'


var Message = mongoose.model('Message', {
    name: String,
    message: String
})

app.get('/messages', (req, res) => {
    Message.find({}, (err, messages) => {
        res.send(messages)
    })
})

app.get('/messages/:user', (req, res) => {
    var user = req.params.user
    Message.find({name: user}, (err, messages) => {
        res.send(messages)
    })
})

app.post('/messages', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        var message = new Message(req.body)

        var savedMessage = await message.save()

        console.log('saved')

        var censored = await Message.findOne({ message: 'badword' })

        if (censored)
            await Message.remove({ _id: censored.id })
        else
            io.emit('message', req.body)

        res.sendStatus(200)
    } catch (error) {
        res.sendStatus(500)
        return console.error(error)
    } finally {
        console.log('message post called')
    }
})


mongoose.connect(dbUrl, { useMongoClient: true }, (err) => {
    console.log('MongoDB status is', err)
})
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue @niv ziv. Did you ever find a solution?